# Create an api and display message using get request

Tags: node.js, express

Create an api in router folder to display information about something and display in express using get request in server.js out of the router folder.

api.js in router folder:

```
function getMessage() {
    console.log('Hello my name something')
}

getMessage()
```

server.js out of router folder::

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const apiHandler = require('./routes/api')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes')));

app.get('/none', apiHandler)

})
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening');
})
```

It gives error::

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

I'm completely new to this so anyone can please make me understand how can I display simple message through route folder creating api and display in server.js file.

Comment: You need to pass a legit route for Express to work. Currently, you're not exporting anything.

Comment: I exported the function and followed the step as suggested by @David R but it's displaying the msg only on the cmd not on the server. How can I display on the server?

Comment: First of all, you're missing opening curly bracket in your `app.get`. You should take a look at the official documentation https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `api.js` you need to export your function using `module.exports` like this,

```
function getMessage(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello my name something');
}

module.exports = getMessage;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's recommended to pass Express parameters ```(req, res, next)```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @mas, Since it was a simple `console.log` I thought of omitting that.

Comment: So I followed your step but its displaying on command prompt only but i want it to display on the server. How to approach to display it on the server? Localhost:3000/non?

Comment: Replace, your `console.log` with `res.send('Hello my name something');` See updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked but can you tell me how did it work?

Comment: @DavidR Right, agree. The thing is; most of the real-world scenarios have action after going through the middleware.

Comment: @Ajax The `module.exports` is a special object which is included in every JS file in the Node.js application by default. module represents your current module and exports is an object that will be get exposed as a module. So, whatever you assign to module.exports or exports, the same will be exposed as a module which can later be accessed from anywhere in your application.

Comment: @mas Yup! I agree with you too!

Comment: Ok so I got the concept of export module and what about (res,req,next) this part. Sorry for trouble but I just want to be clear.

Comment: @Ajax Basically, those are (`req` and `res`) the callback objects which you get in return when you make any GET (or) POST request to it from your `server.js`, The `next` enables you to pass the control/process to the next route which has the same `/none` with different parameters for processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it. :)